# First domain-driven User entity class

Tags: php, object-oriented, ddd

I'm still learning about domain driven design, and I have created my first entity class `User`.

Is this fully compliant with the DDD principles?  Particularly my setters because I have business rules in them.  Any other suggestions would be highly appreciated as well.

```
namespace Models\Entities;

class User
{
    private $id;
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $registerDate;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        if (!$this->id) {
            if (is_int($id) && $id >= 1) {
                $this->id = $id;

                return $this;
            }

            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('ID must be a positive integer.');
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('ID has already been set.');
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        if (is_string($firstName) && !empty($firstName) && ctype_alpha($firstName)) {
            $length = $this->stringLength($firstName);

            if ($length >= 1 && $length <= 35) {
                $this->firstName = $firstName;

                return $this;
            }
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('First name must be an alpha string inclusively between 1 and 35 characters.');
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        if (is_string($lastName) && !empty($lastName) && ctype_alpha($lastName)) {
            $length = $this->stringLength($lastName);

            if ($length >= 1 && $length <= 35) {
                $this->lastName = $lastName;

                return $this;
            }
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Last name must be an alpha string inclusively between 1 and 35 characters.');
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        if (is_string($email) && !empty($email)) {
            $sanitized = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $isValid   = filter_var($sanitized, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
            $isValid   = $isValid ? $this->stringLength($email) <= 254 : false;

            if ($email === $sanitized && $isValid) {
                $this->email = $email;

                return $this;
            }
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Email must be a string in this format: "[local]@[domain].[ext]".');
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        if (is_string($password) && !empty($password)) {
            $length = $this->stringLength($password);

            if ($length >= 6 && $length <= 60) {
                $this->password = $password;

                return $this;
            }
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Password must be a string inclusively between 6 and 60 characters.');
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setRegisterDate($date)
    {
        if (is_int($date) && !empty($date)) {
            // TO DO: date validation unix timestamp is_int

            $this->registerDate = $date;

            return $this;
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Register date must be an integer and valid unix timestamp.');
    }

    public function getRegisterDate()
    {
        return $this->registerDate;
    }

    private function stringLength($input)
    {
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($input);
        $length   = mb_strlen($input, $encoding);

        return $length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class can absolutely be considered like a DDD domain entity.
However, I would suggest some improvements:

- DDD likes to use an ObjectValue for the unique identifiers, you could use one instead of a simple integer.
- You could separate the validation logic from the entity (not specific to DDD).
- You should not have a `getPassword()` method but a `verifyPassword($password)` instead. Don't expose the password in plain text.
- You could also separate the `stringLength()` into its own string utility class.
- Regarding the use of a Uniw timestamp, keep in mind that `DateTime` is a better option since it embeds the time zone. Timestamps don't, which is always confusing when handling dates from all over the world...

Answer (score 3):

Like ***Keven*** stated:

> bring a utility function like the calculation of the length of a string in a separate class with other methods similar to this one.

For example:

```
class Utility
{
    public static function getStringLength($input)
    {
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($input);
        $length = mb_strlen($input, $encoding);
        return $length;
    }
}

//Usage:
echo Utility::getStringLength("CodeReview");
```

Same goes for methods that check for a certain range, or check for integer values:

```
public static function isInRange($i, $min, $max)
{
    return ($i >= $min && $i <= $max);
}

//Usage:
echo Utility::isInRange($someUnknownIntVar, 10, 20);
```

For your code example I've created following class:

```
class Utility
{
    public static function isNonEmptyString($input)
    {
        return (!empty($input) && is_string($input));
    }

    public static function getStringLength($input)
    {
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($input);
        $length = mb_strlen($input, $encoding);
        return $length;
    }

    public static function isInt($i)
    {
        return (!empty($i) && is_int($i));
    }

    public static function isPositiveInt($i)
    {
        return (self::isInt($i) && $i > 0);
    }

    public static function isInRange($i, $min, $max)
    {
        return ($i >= $min && $i <= $max);
    }

    public static function isValidEmail($email)
    {
        $sanitized = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $isValid = filter_var($sanitized, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        return $isValid;
    }
}
```

Also mentioned is that an entity should not actually containt any logic. Define another class specifically for validation on the properties. You *can* add validation methods to the `Utility` class if you want but I'd keep them separated. This way the `Utility` class can be used in other projects without having to modify them. Here's an example of a `Validator` class:

```
class Validator
{
    public static function isValidName($name)
    {
        $isValidName = (Utility::isNonEmptyString($name) && ctype_alpha($name));
        $isValidName = $isValidName ? Utility::isInRange(Utility::getStringLength($name), 1, 35) : false;
        return $isValidName;
    }

    public static function isValidPassWord($pass)
    {
        $isValidPass = Utility::isNonEmptyString($pass);
        $isValidPass = $isValidPass ? Utility::isInRange(Utility::getStringLength($pass), 6, 60) : false;
        return $isValidPass;
    }

    public static function isValidEmailAddress($email)
    {
        $isValidEmail = Utility::isValidEmail($email);
        $isValidEmail = $isValidEmail ? Utility::isInRange(Utility::getStringLength($email), 0, 254) : false;
        return $isValidEmail;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of this:

```
public function setEmail($email)
{
    if (is_string($email) && !empty($email)) {
        $sanitized = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $isValid   = filter_var($sanitized, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $isValid   = $isValid ? $this->stringLength($email) <= 254 : false;

        if ($email === $sanitized && $isValid) {
            $this->email = $email;

            return $this;
        }
    }

    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Email must be a string in this format: "[local]@[domain].[ext]".');
}
```

You'll get this clean code (which goes for all your properties like password, name, ...):

```
public function setEmail($email)
{
    if (Validator::isValidEmailAddress($email)) {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Email must be a string in this format: "[local]@[domain].[ext]".');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be considered a DDD entity, but all validation logic in the setters could be moved to an invariants checking method, that could clean the methods, bringing space to implement more interesting business logic.

```
public boolean checkInvariants() {

    //Check first name

    //Check lastname

    //Check e-mail 

    //And so on...

}
```

It also could have more expressive methods aligned with the ubiquitous language, not only getters and setters, something like:

```
public String fullName() { return firstName + " " + lastName; }

public void doLogin() { ... }
```